# NHibernte CreateAlias for 2 multiply class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I have 3 classes: Book, Genre, Authors

```
public class Book {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual int MfRaiting { get; set; }

    public virtual int PageNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Genre> Genres { get; set; }


    public virtual Series Series { get; set; }

    public virtual Mind Mind { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    public Book() {
        Genres = new List<Genre>();
        Authors = new List<Author>();
    }

}
public class Genre {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public Genre() {
        Books=new List<Book>();
    }
}
public class Author {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual string SurName { get; set; }

    public virtual string Biography { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public Author() {
        Books=new List<Book>();
    }
}
```

And his classMaps

```
public class BookMap : ClassMap<Book> {
    public BookMap() {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Genres)
            .Cascade.All()
            .Table("Book_Genre");
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Authors)
            .Cascade.All()
            .Table("Book_Author");
        References(x => x.Series);
        HasOne(x => x.Mind).Constrained();
    }
}
public class GenreMap : ClassMap<Genre> {
    public GenreMap() {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Books)
            .Cascade.All()
            .Inverse()
            .Table("Book_Genre");
    }
}
public class AuthorMap : ClassMap<Author> {
    public AuthorMap() {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.SurName);
        Map(x => x.Biography);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Books)
            .Cascade.All()
            .Inverse()
            .Table("Book_Author");
    }
}
```

When i try write in code 
var criteria = session.CreateCriteria();
    criteria.CreateAlias("Genres", "genre", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
it works well, but when i do so

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var criteria = session.CreateCriteria<Book>();
   criteria.CreateAlias("Genres", "genre", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
   criteria.CreateAlias("Authors", "author", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
   criteria.SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());
}
```

i see exception Cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags. How can I get result of that criteria?

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem! I replace IList on ISet, and replace new List<"Class"> on new HashSet<"Class">

I read this problem here.
http://developer-should-know.tumblr.com/post/118012584847/jpa-fetching-strategies Only one collection that is fetched using JOIN strategy can be of type List, other collection must be of type Set. Otherwise an exception will be thrown:

HibernateException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags